# Unable to Create .exe file using PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am attempting to create an .exe file for a single file Selenium python script. After I run pyinstaller it appears to successfully build the .exe "Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.", but there is no file in the dist directory other than a .file.

After some research, it looks like I may need to edit the .spec file to include missing files/packages pyinstaller could not automatically find. I am not sure where to begin on determining what is missing if this is the case. I also have a warn- file with a list of about 30 "missing module". Do these need to be added to the .spec file?

Comment: Given that Python and Selenium both work pretty much everywhere, why would you turn this into a Windows-specific executable that would be drastically bigger than just... your .py or .pyc file?

Comment: It is going to be used by users with Windows OS where python may not be installed

Comment: So just... tell them to install python? It's a free install in the Microsoft store. Giving them a giant .exe that packs Python_and_ Selenium in is a worse solution in every way =/

Comment: I didn't think python had to be installed on the computer running the .exe? This is going to be for non-technical users, having them install python isn't really an option

Comment: pyinstaller creates an executable that _includes_ python itself, in dll form, just in a way that no one can ever use it for anything else. That said: please explain your setup. If I create a new venv, install selenium and pypackage in that, and then create a `test.py` with the content from https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html and compile that to exe, things work just fine (it also turns a 395 byte script into an insane 1.7Mb executable)